# Get the response text from server(Android)

Tags: android, response

I am getting the server response through the following code in Asynctask

```
 try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", emailText));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwordText));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            Log.e("post_", nameValuePairs.toString());
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            serverResponse=EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.e("RESPONSE1",serverResponse);
            return serverResponse;
        }
```

Value of serverResponse will be either fail or success which I am getting in the Log.
And on button click I am checking the value of serverResponse for navigating to another activity.But the value of serverResponse on button click is null.So I am getting nullpointer exception.

```
 loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            emailText=loginemail.getText().toString();
            passwordText=loginpassword.getText().toString();
            new loginData().execute(emailText, passwordText);
             Log.e("SERVERRESPONSE1",serverResponse);
            if (serverResponse =="Success" ) {
                Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),IndexActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if (serverResponse=="Fail"){
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Invalid Username/Password!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Invalid Username/Password!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I get the corect value of response in button click?

Comment: Please add the detailed code and also paste logcat output.

Comment: I have edited now..please check

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in `onPostExecute()` method of `loginData` class.

```
Log.e("SERVERRESPONSE1",serverResponse);
if(serverResponse.equals("Success") ) {
    Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),IndexActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
} else if (serverResponse.equals("Fail")){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Invalid Username/Password!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Invalid Username/Password!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

And remove it from `onClick()` method.

You should notify user after getting response from the asynctask.
Go through this link to understand [how AsyncTask works](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: But now also I am not able to navigate to another activity.(I am getting success message)

Comment: try replacing getApplicationContext() with YourActivity.this

That may help you.

Comment: @Divya-Thanks a lot for your help..:)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a null error because you're not giving the async task time to finish before checking the serverResponse. The appropriate approach would be to handle that logic within the `onPostExecute` portion of your async task. Something like this...

```
public class GetServerResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
 String emailText, passwordText;


public GetDetailsAsyncTask(String emailText, String passwordText) {
     this.emailText=emailText;
     this.passwordText = passwordText;
}



@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

    if (isCancelled())
        return null;
    return [Call Method that accepts emailText and passwordText && returns a string (response text)];
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String serverResponse) {
    if(serverResponse!=null){
        if (serverResponse =="Success" ) {
            Intent i= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),IndexActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
        else if (serverResponse=="Fail"){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Invalid Username/Password!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Invalid Username/Password!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

}
```

If you want a callback to the wrapping activity you could do as follows...

```
//inside the async task class
public void setListener(onServerResponselistener listener) {
    this.mListener = listener;
}

public interface onServerResponselistener{
    public void success();

    public void fail();
}

//then in your post execute, you could call this.mListener.success()/fail() depending on the response. Make sure to check for null.
```

Then in your wrapping activity/class you can do the following...

```
  GetServerResponse oReturn = new GetServerResponse (email,password);
    oReturn.setListener(new onServerResponselistener () {

        @Override
        public void success() {
        //handle a successful call
        //go to the next activity
        }

        @Override
        public void fail() {
        //popup "incorrect credentials etc."
        }
    });
oReturn.execute();
```

Comment: But now also I am not able to navigate to another activity.(I am getting success message)

Comment: @AmitNair - you could implement an interface in which the wrapping activity could overwrite. I'll update the code

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help..:)